# Why is json2 slow on long arrays?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the [json2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to parse a json file but it's very very slow. It takes about 25minutes to parse the file. The file itself is about 10mb in size and it mostly a few arrays with tens of thousands of items. Each item is sub-arrays with numbers (a 4x4 matrix).

For shorter arrays (up to around a thosand items) it seems to be quite fast. What is the reason that it becomes so slow with longer arrays? Is there a way to speed it up?

- I'm using Adobes ExtendScript which is based on ECMA-262 Standard (I belive) so there is no built-in json parser.

Sample code:

```
f = new File(filepath)

f.open("r")
f.encoding = "UTF-8";
var content = f.read()
f.close();

obj = JSON.parse(content)
```

Comment: Show the code how you are parsing it.

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer.